# What should our chatroom name be?

Tags: discussion, suggestions, chat

Currently, our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) name is "Hinduism". Are we going to stick with it? If not, what should we change it to?

*Note: Feel free to add your chatroom name suggestions as answers.*

Comment: Seems reasonable, c.2020 there is good participation with that name, and the name is very understandable. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest that (for now, anyway) we stick with **Hinduism**. We want to make sure that the chatroom is easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sanatan Dharma

*Note: But I think this may not be easy to find other users (outers)! However, we can use this name like other communities do*

<sup>Related: [Should we change the community name to Sanatana Dharma?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/270/277)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend having a constant name and a subheading. Like the following:

> **Hinduism: *any variable short phrase***

We can keep the word Hinduism constant forever. Few of us would be the room owners and they can change the short phrase once in a while. The phrase should be related to Hinduism, mythology etc. Below are a few examples:

> Hinduism: The Flying Pushpak
>
> Hinduism: Here rest the vedas

Answer (score -2):

#### Vedic Dharma

<sup>obviously!</sup>

Answer (score -2):

### Satsanga

Hope whom we meet is gentle and the talk would be significant. Satsanga is very important in our life for Yoga and spiritual progress.

Answer (score -3):

To me "**Pushpak**" seems nice.

- Taken from "Pushpak vimaan" (*ancient mythology aeroplane*)

Answer (score -4):

Based on nature of the room Hinduism ,Which is main Chat- room of our Hinduism Stack Exchange site.I would suggest two good names.As suggested by @Pandya "Sanatan Dharma" is also a good name ,but I would like to further add the word "Sarita (सरिता) ,which means River to It.

So the name will be **Sanatan Dharma Sarita** (सनातन धर्म सरिता).The idea is to show the similarity between a River and the chat room .as the new questions always been displayed on that room and which is always flowing ie.something always going on in that room.

Also **Hindu Dharma  Pushpa Sarita** (हिंदू धर्म पुष्प सरिता) is good name.Here the concept of flower is used.