# Should we change the community name to Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: discussion, suggestions

"Hindu" or "Hinduism" is the name given to Hindus by Britishers and other people while the Vedas and even Lord Krishna Himself referred to it as `Sanatana Dharma`. So shouldn't we change the name of this site from "Hinduism Stack Exchange" to the actual name "Sanatana Dharma Stack Exchange"?

Before downvoting or criticizing, please express your views.

Comment: +1 I agree with you. but "Sanatana Dharma" was not a religion, it was just a common practice. "Hinduism" is a religion. So, a little bit confused.

Comment: @Mr_Green -Sanatan is the sanskrit world for the oldest one or the eldest one of all Sanatan goes beyond worldly boundaries and is beyond time that's why we worship god's like shiva the mahankaal the kaal of kaal means (one who created time!), also hindu is one derived from sindhu a geogrophical worldly name!!.

Comment: Lets just go with what the religion is known today as. Just for convenience sake.

Comment: I don't think convince is more important than truth or speaking frankly sanatan is more heavey word and more attractive + it is the one described in vedas how can we say that we are the son of the ved vyasa and other great sages who were sanatan worshippers??? Just think about it deeply

Comment: If you change it to Sanatan dharma, then even most Hindus will pass by the proposal without realising it's about Hinduism. Why not change the name of India to Hindustan while we're at it? Move forward, not backward!

Comment: See Sanatan is our past we should integrate past with future not change the past in order to comfort ourselves

Comment: [off-topic] @a20 actually, it should be "Bharat" not "Hindustan".

Comment: @Creator according to you we all should try and live like our grandfathers to "integrate past with future"? ;)

Comment: I am talking about sages of the great ages the drishta's who actually created vedanta lifestyle and lived like an example also the great vishnu avatar's with the modern approach to live a ideal life in this silicon age with vedanta.

Comment: @Yogi - excellent question :)

Comment: I would like this. +1

Comment: @moonstar2001, have tried to revive this discussion here: [Should this site be renamed to dharma.stackexchange.com?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/947/1049)

Comment: I would just put it in the description of the site. "Hinduism—known to adherents as Sanatana Dharma—is the..."

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: I don't think we should change it. One of the main purposes of our site is to provide authentic information about Hinduism and most people only know Vedic Religion by the name Hinduism.

---

As the question asks:

> <sub>Before Down-voting or Criticizing please express your views.</sub>

I'm expressing my views here.

First understand the term:

**Sanatana Dharma**

Sanatana means Eternal and Dharma means Religion.

#### Why Hinduism/ Vedic Religion is Sanatana Dharma ?

There are mainly two reasons for calling Hinduism/ Vedic religion as Sanatana Dharma:

> 1) It has no origin. It is coming from time beginning. And it was even in previous creation. RigVeda 10.190.3 states "Ordainer created Sun and Moon like that of previous creation."
>
> 2) It is based on Vedas and Vedas are recompiled in every Dwapara by Veda Vyasa. As one can see in [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/who-all-were-the-different-ved-vyas/3618#3618) there have been 28 Veda Vyasa only in this Manvantara. *There were 1131 Shakhas of Vedas and upto now all are lost and we have only about 10 Shakhas of Vedas.* We have lost various texts of Samhitas itself. But even with this loss Vedic text will not be lost, because Ashwatthama is going to become next Vyasa in next Dwapara and he will recompile all those lost texts. *So as in every Yuga a person comes as a Vedavyas and restores lost text of Vedas and revives Vedas, Vedas are not lost.*

**As Vedas are not lost due to this cyclic nature of their revival of the same texts. So, it means religion based on Vedas will also remain eternal.**

In this way Vedic religion is eternal and it comes under category of Sanatana Dharma  ie. Our religion Vedic Sanatana Dharma is Eternal.

#### Is Hinduism/ Vedic religion the only Sanatana Dharma?

As we discussed in above how Vedic religion is eternal. We discussed two main points there:

> i) It should not have any origin point.
>
> ii) It should be revived as cyclic phenomena, so that religion is never lost.

So, Is Vedic Religion the only religion to fulfill this Criteria?

If we see only with respect to Vedic scripture we can say yes. But if we judge with religions of their scripture. We come to the answer **No.**

### 1) Buddhism:

Most people might think that Siddhartha Gautama who latter became **Gautam Buddha** is the founder of Buddhism. And as it was founded some 2500 yrs. ago and as we see it's origin it isn't eternal and thus Buddhism is not eternal religion. But Is this true with respect to Buddhist scripture?
**A Big No.**

Buddhism doesn't regard Gautam Buddha as founder of Buddhism. But he is just one among the many Buddhas.
There were previous Buddhas before the present Buddha.

Actually as per Buddhist texts Present Buddha ie. Gautam Buddha is 4th Buddha of this Kalpa. The 3rd Buddha being [**Kassapa Buddha**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kassapa_Buddha) , 2nd Buddha being [Konagamana Buddha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko%E1%B9%87%C4%81gamana_Buddha) and the 1st Buddha of this kalpa being [Kakusandha Buddha](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakusandha_Buddha). And the upcoming ie. 5th Buddha of this Kalpa being [**Maitreya Buddha**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya).

Present Buddha Maitreya is living in Tusita heaven now and will come to earth when teachings of present Buddha is lost and again revive Buddhism.

Just as Hinduism calls this Kalpa as Shweta Varaha kalpa, **Buddhism calls this Kalpa as Bhadra Kalpa** and it is also of duration of billions of years. Buddhist text also provide a list of 27 [**previous Buddhas**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_named_Buddhas) including Buddha of Previous Kalpas also.

Thus Buddhism also has no origin and it was also in previous creation and it is also revived again and again by coming Buddhas from Tusita loka (as per Buddhist text). Thus Buddhism is also **Bauddha Sanatana Dharma.**

### 2) Jainism

Most people again think **Mahavira Jain** is the founder of Jainism and as it has origin it can't be called Sanatana Dharma. Again this is wrong as per Jain scripture.

In Jainisim also Mahavira Jain is only one among the 24 Tirthankars of Jain. ie. He only Revived Jain Religion.

Just as Veda Vyas comes in cycles in Hinduism, similarly in Jainism 24 Tirthankars come in one cosmic cycle of this world. The present or 24th [**Tirthankara**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirthankara) being Mahavira Jain.

Actually we have also some historical records of 23rd Tirthankara named [**Parshavanatha**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parshvanatha)

So, Jains strongly believe in cyclic revival of Dharma. They also have concepts of Vasudeva, Baladeva and Prativasudeva.

So, Jainism also fulfills the criteria of being called **Jaina Sanatana Dharma.**

what about:

#### Islam:

Although Quran claims that there were messengers sent by Allah before Prophet Muhammad all over the world. But Quranic text declares that **Prophet Muhammad is the last messengers of Allah.** Thus it stops the possibility of cyclic revival of Dharma. Neither there is a statement that there were Previous Muhammad who gave Quran. Nor a person named Prophet Muhammed will come to give Quran again as Prophet Muhammad is considered the final messenger.

So, it doesn't fulfill our criteria of calling **Islamic Sanatana Dharma.**

#### Christianity:

Although there is a concept in Christianity about **2nd coming of Jesus.** But nowhere it is told that there were previous Jesuses and they come like in cycle to revive Christianity again and again. Also we do not find statements of cyclic nature of creation and Jesus giving Bible in previous creation.

So, it doesn't fulfill our criteria of calling **Christian Sanatana Dharma.**

### Sanatana Dharma:

So if we go by scripture of respective religion, we find Vedic Religion, Bauddha Religion and Jaina Religion as Sanatana Dharma. Both Jainism and Buddhism also uses the Sanskrit words and the terms Sanatana and Dharma. Buddhism also uses the pali term Dhamma to denote it. Thus we have three religions in the list of Sanatana Dharma:

1) **Vedic Sanatana Dharma.**

2) **Bauddha Sanatana Dharma.**

3) **Jaina Sanatana Dharma.**

So, the precise term for our religion becomes **Vedic Sanatana Dharma** and not only **Sanatana Dharma.**

#### Objector:

There is no proof that there were previous Buddhas and previous Tirthankaras (except Parshavanatha). So it is not true.

#### We reply:

There is also no proof that there were previous Veda Vyasa. We are telling it as per our scripture and they are telling it as per their scripture.

### Objector:

Why should we believe in their scripture?. We believe in Vedas which are eternal.

### We reply:

Why should they believe in our scripture? They believe in their scripture. And they do not believe Vedas are eternal. Why should they believe?

### So we should change our site name to *Vedic Sanatana Dharma.?*

I don't think we should change it. **One of the main purpose of our site is to provide authentic information about Hinduism and most people only know Vedic Religion by the name Hinduism.**

In such condition if we change the name of Hinduism to other site it will become less popular. And most people will be trapped in many degraded answers which are present in **Quora** and other site. As they use the name Hinduism and people will be misguided.

As one of our main purpose is to provide authentic information about Hinduism to the world. Hence I believe we should act in that way. Hence I believe we should keep our site name as same. ie.

[**hinduism.stackexchange.com**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/)

This is just only my View. People may agree or disagree. And the community members may decide further in this matter.

One may comment whether one agrees or disagrees with my Views.

**Thank You!**

Comment: I agree with you on the point of popularity of the name 'Hindu', but I  disagree on the point of Jain Sanatana Dharma and Buddhist Sanatana Dharma. If you analyze origin of Jainism and Buddhism they are originated from Solar Dynasty and Koshala empire respectively, which followed Vedic Dharama inherently. So it's the other way around they derived their belifs from Vedic Sanatana Dharma by spreading false/corrupt beliefs. If you want any logical proof on how nastika schools are false then read Adi Shankaracharya's Commentary on Bramhasutras.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46271/discussion-on-answer-by-tezz-should-we-change-the-community-name-to-sanatan-dhar).

Comment: How about preferring "Hindu Dharma" over "Hinduism"?

Answer (score -1):

From [What is the origin of the word “Hindu”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/65/277), It is clear that:

- > The word “Hindu” was originally coined by the ancient Persians to describe the people living east of the “Sindhu”, or Indus River.
- > It was the name given by Islamic invaders. To them everyone living beyond the river Sindhu were Hindus including Buddhists, Jains & animistic tribals. Sindhu becomes Hindu in Persian and Indus in English.

Also it seems unable to support [Authenticity of Sanskrit Verses containing the word “HINDU”](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10269/277).

So, I think ***we can say the original name of Hinduism is "Sanatan Dharma" (सनातन धर्म)***. Refer the the meaning of Sanskrit word [सनातन](http://sanskritdictionary.com/san%C4%81tana/248528/1) which is also discussed as [Why "Hidnu Dharma" and "Sanatan Dharma" are synonym?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9981/277)<sup>(Though it is old post of mine when I wasn't know much information/knowledge)</sup>.

---

Some may argue that others may find it difficult to understand "Sanatan Dharma" as a site name. (They may not get the idea about what the site refers to) but I want to say [All Sites - StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and [Area51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) clearly say:

> Q&A for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about Hinduism

So, Others can easily got/understand what the site refers to by reading the description of site.

And at the [Tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) page we can write:

> **Sanatan Dharma** Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about **Hinduism**.

So, I think there is no such problem/confusion (or possible issue is solved from description of site at all!) if we use Sanatan Dharma.

---

<sup>Note: This may be obsolete discussion (kept for historical reason).</sup>

---

<sup>Note: The another good thing is to [implement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/374/277) ॐ as Symobl/Favicon for our site which is enough to represent Sanatan Dharma.</sup>

Comment: Yeah your proposals are good. We may have to explain the users about the name Sanatana and why we use that name.

Comment: I agree with @Bharat's comment under the question. I rarely hear any Hindus calling themselves "I'm a Sanatana Dharmi" or their scriptures "Sanatana Dharma scriptures" so I don't understand why should the 'religion' be called Sanatana Dharma. I do agree we need a new icon so I upvoted the linked question.

Comment: @sv That is because of indoctrination. Sringeri Jagadguru has clearly instructed us that we should refer to ourselves as sanatana dharmaanujaaya's i.e., those in sanatana dharma's lineage and the religion is indeed sanatana dharma.