# Can we have a different favicon (ॐ) for Hinduism SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, favicon

Generally, questions from other Stack Exchange sites are shown on the right side of the screen while reading our Hinduism questions/answers and most of them have favicons associated with them. For example, a chef's cap for questions from Cooking Stack Exchange. I was just wondering why we don't have a logo like that for our site. In case it is agreeable then I would like to propose the **ॐ** symbol for our favicon, as the current favicon "Hi" seems quite vague and irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that Om would be the most excellent symbol for the site. But I think Keshav is correct.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda, I think we already have a favicon now, it shows 'Hi', ie, first 2 letters from Hinduism. But this seems to be meaningless. I think when I asked question that time we dont have any favicon.

Comment: I have posted a question regarding this on main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/how-can-we-change-the-favicon-of-se-site-in-beta

Comment: @Aby. No. If you go to www.stackexchange.com and look at 'all sites' you can see all the sites - the ones with logos and those without. Hi not really a logo, looks like all the other beta sites.

Comment: "Hi" do seems weird to me, I do love to see "'ॐ' as our favicon but even after a year no response yet :/

Comment: I believe **ॐ** would be *perfect* favicon for our community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After more internal discussion and comments under this meta post, we agreed that ॐ would indeed be a good favicon for this site. We forwarded the request to our design team a little while ago, and they came back to us with the new icons today. They should be appearing soon if not already, depending on caching. Thank you for bearing with us!

Here's how it should now look:

[image]

Comment: @sv. Good one. Saffron ॐ would be best instead of White and Black.

Comment: @TheDestroyer don't be greedy. Wait for graduation for rest of teh colour/design request

Comment: @Pops: thanks ...

Comment: Looks great, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks to Designer Team,  Shog9 and Pops !

Comment: @Pops Thanks a lot for getting this approved. Its really worth the wait. Icon looks great.

Answer (score -6):

First off, sorry for not getting to this sooner. I wish I had a good excuse, but honestly the post just fell through the cracks until I was poked about it again recently.

I can start by at least telling you the origin of the current favicon: the first two letters of the (English) word "Hinduism." Perhaps not the best symbol for your community, but fairly standard for our favicon designs. All beta sites have favicons based on the light blue "Stack Exchange Q&A balloon" shape, mostly (but not always) containing two letters. More customized favicons, like the chef's hat you mentioned, are part of the site design that graduated sites get.

That said, the first thing I did to look into your actual request was figuring out why you wanted the ॐ symbol. From what I can tell, it is the most common representation of OM (or AUM), an icon/sound of great importance in Hinduism. On those grounds, it seems like it would be a good choice.

However, I also saw that OM and the ॐ character is also important to other religions, such as Buddhism and Jainism. There's even [a question on Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/what-is-the-meaning-of-om-mani-padme-hung) that references it. That shared usage disqualifies it, I think. A good favicon should be pretty unambiguous; in other words, when you see it, you shouldn't be left wondering which site it represents.

My usual caveat applies here: I'm not an expert in the topic, so I had to go do some research and it's possible I didn't get the full picture. If you think I've missed something significant, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Om might be used in Buddhism but it immediately signifies Hinduism.

Comment: Trust me, ॐ is the universal symbol of Hinduism.  When we're talking about what religion people would think of when they see that symbol, it would unambiguously be Hinduism.

Comment: If you see Chronological order of Dharmic faiths, Hinduism is oldest among them and indeed oldest among all existing faiths. So, ॐ  with no second thought represents verily Sanatana Dharma aka Hinduism, though other Dharmic faiths adopted it later.

Comment: This is like saying that since Islam also believes in Jesus being a prophet, a picture of Jesus cannot be a good representative favicon of Christianity Stack Exchange. AUM is the essence of Hinduism. :) There's nothing that would represent Hinduism universally accepted by all Hindus other than AUM AFAIK.

Comment: So, finally can you remove tag `status-declined`?

Comment: On @Pops's request, we're having another community manager look into this for a second opinion. Stay tuned!

Comment: @hairboat Thanks for considering it. If any query/explanation/clarification, discuss at [Vedanta and Philosophy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/discussion-on-vedanta-and-philosophy) or [Hinduism](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).

Comment: @hairboat any update on it?

Comment: Visit [Is there an universal symbol for Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2226/277)

Comment: Visit [Sacred-Texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/index.htm) and which symbol you find?

Comment: Do we still need this answer as we have got our fav icon?

Comment: @TheDestroyer why not, it shows  a good counter argument for the suggestion